# how to display size of folders MacOS via du

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I'm trying to display size of subfolders in my Download forlder via:

```
du -sh
```

output isL

```
6.2G    .
```

Is there any way to display it as:

```
folder1    1.2G
folder2    0.2G
folder3    2.6G
folder4    5.9G
```

But without any `subfolders` (I don't need to see size of all folders into `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3` )

Comment: did you try `du -h -d 1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use command like this:

```
du -h -d 1 | sort -hr
```

you should get **output**:

```
1.2G    folder1
0.2G    folder2
2.6G    folder3
5.9G    folder4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
du -hd 1
```

Sample output (on Ubuntu 16.04, `du (GNU coreutils) 8.25`):

```
1.2G    ./folder1
200M    ./folder2
2.6G    ./folder3
5.9G    ./folder4
9G      .
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may also help you which will help you to:

I- Have a variable in this command so that you could pass any directory
   name there.

II- You could set level till you want to see the folder.

III- structure's details. It will give output in size's increasing order.

```
du  "$val" -hk --max-depth=2 | sort -nr
```